# Sending Data To Socket is Causing an Exception

Tags: c++, boost-asio

When I call the start_receive() method in the code below without the _outSocket.send() call, the method receives data from the socket with no issues, but when I try to send the data out on another socket a boost exception is thrown.  I'm not sure what's causing the issue, so any help would be great.

```
#include "dataproxy.h"
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace boost::asio;

DataProxy::DataProxy(boost::asio::io_service& ioserv)
: _inSocket(ioserv, ip::udp::endpoint(ip::udp::v4(), 5004))
,_outSocket(ioserv, ip::udp::endpoint(ip::udp::v4(), 5005))
{   
}

DataProxy::~DataProxy()
{

}

void DataProxy::start(){
    QThread::start();
}

void DataProxy::run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        start_receive();
    }
}

void DataProxy::start_receive()
{
    /*_inSocket.async_receive_from(
    boost::asio::buffer(_inBuffer), _videoEndpoint,
    boost::bind(&DataProxy::handleIncomingData, this,
    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    */
    size_t reply_length = _inSocket.receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer(_inBuffer), _dataSourceEndpoint);

    std::cout << "Received " << reply_length << " bytes" << std::endl;

    //This is the line that causes the exception
    size_t send_length = _outSocket.send(boost::asio::buffer(_inBuffer));

}
```

Comment: What is the error message of the exception?

Comment: I try to catch const boost::system::error_code& ex but I still get the message "Unhandled exception at 0x76e4b727 in RVT.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::system::system_error at memory location 0x04f0f634.."

Comment: What type is `_inBuffer`? Have you tried including `reply_length` when instantiating the `buffer` in `send()`?

Comment: boost::array<char, 65000> _inBuffer;

Comment: Fixed the problem using the following code, I removed the _outSocket completely.  I will of course change the name of _inSocket to be more appropriate. 

    ip::udp::endpoint destinationEndpoint(ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"),5005);
    _inSocket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(_inBuffer), destinationEndpoint);

Comment: @Slruh provide an answer if you have indeed solved your own question.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure what's causing the issue

The `system_error` exception is being thrown because the `send()` method you have [chosen to use](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/send/overload1.html) throws an exception that you are not handling. Either handle the exception inside a `try` and `catch` block, or use one of the [overloads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/send.html) that do not throw. There's a variety of reasons for any of the error conditions from `send`, consult the documentation for more information.

> any help would be great

My best guess is that you are invoking the `send()` method on an unconnected UDP socket. Perhaps you intended to invoke [send_to()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/send_to.html) since you received the data using `receive_from()` and not `receive()`?